# RecyclerView and Toolbar not found

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I'm having problems with a recyclerView.
This is the definition in the xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbMenuDetalle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcyViatgesDetall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I try to use it  in the following class:

```
public class ViatgeDetall extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRcyViatgesDetall;
    private AdapterViatgesDetall mAdapterViatgesDetall;
    private ViatgesManager.Viatge mViatge;

    private ArrayList<ViatgesManager.Viatge> viatges;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tlbMenuDetalle);
       setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TravelApp");
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        Log.d("myTag", "Detalle OnCreate" );
        mRcyViatgesDetall = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyViatgesDetall);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            viatges  = ViatgesManager.ITEMS;
            int f = getIntent().getIntExtra("viatge",0);
            mViatge = viatges.get(f-1);
            Log.d("myTag", "Detalle OnCreate" + mViatge.getName());
        }
        ArrayList<ViatgesManager.Stop> stops =  mViatge.getStops();


        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        glm.setOrientation(GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        mRcyViatgesDetall.setLayoutManager(llm);

        mAdapterViatgesDetall = new AdapterViatgesDetall(stops, this);
        mRcyViatgesDetall.setAdapter(mAdapterViatgesDetall);



    }
}
```

I don't see what i'm doing worng, beacuse i keep getting this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.usuari.myapplication3, PID: 26507
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.usuari.myapplication3/com.example.usuari.myapplication3.ViatgeDetall}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on
>   a null object reference
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on
>   a null object reference
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.usuari.myapplication3.ViatgeDetall.onCreate(ViatgeDetall.java:37)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Even if i comment the part about the toolbar i get a very similar error but with the RecyclerView. I'm working with sdk 25 if that helps...

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usuari.myapplication3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditViatge"
            android:label="EditVIatge"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViatgeDetall"
            android:label="ViatgeDetall"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how does your activity in your manifest look like? (and in your style?) because if you have it already in your layout you don't need to set it in your code again.

Comment: Edited with my manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add correct layout file I think you put incorrect layout file name

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was in :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

That wasn't the correct layout to set.Instead it should had been the layout of the prevoiusly shown xml...